# regular expression to parse image url from a html code

Tags: regex, html-parsing, preg-match

Hello guys i wrote a module that creates some articles and css them properly and i want to parse the images from the Article content. The first thought came to my mind was the regular expressions. i didnt have any idea till 3 hours i started reading tutorials about regexp and i made a pattern that for me it seems kinda ok.

```
$pattern='^src\="images\/([a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+)+([a-zA-Z]*|[0-9]*)*\.[jpg|png|bmp|gif]"$';
$regstring=$introtext;
preg_match($pattern,$regstring,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

INPUT:

```
<p>ASDADSDSASADSADSASDADSDSASADSADSASDADSDSASA</p>
<p><img src="images/authentic.jpg" alt="authentic" /></p>
<p>SASDADSDSASADSADSASDADSDSASADSADS</p>
```

I kinda found alot of ready patters in stackoverflow that are completly different than mine, and i didnt want to just copy some lines that i dont know what they do.Also i found out ten mins before that i can do that With DOM html , but im stubborn to make it work with regexpr so i can learn something more about it. 
Can someone help me find what is my mistake/s ?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't use regex, use DOM ...

Comment: as i allready mentioned i wanted to achieve it with regexp first, so i wont waste all my reading

Comment: Well you have many mistakes in your pattern. `1)` You have no [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). `2)` Your alternation should be in one class, i.e `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` and the quantifier placed outside the groups `()+` should be removed. `3)` You cannot use whole words inside of a character class, so you should replace the last class with a group instead, i.e `(?:jpg|png|bmp|gif)`. Good luck.

Comment: could i ask what is the ?: stands for ?

Comment: Yes, it is a non-capturing group. You can read about grouping constructs [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
src="images\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(?:jpg|png|bmp|gif)"
```

You can try this.A simple version of your regex.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/36

Comment: ~^src\="images\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.(?:jpg|png|bmp|gif)"$~ this was the code i made with the help of @hwnd , so the "=" doesnt need to get escaped with / ? Also thanks for the answer.

Comment: @IseNgaRt try the demo site with other inputs to learn more.See at the right side for explanation.

Comment: Don't teach others do do the things the wrong way, thanks. Regex are not the right tool here !

Comment: @sputnick the OP says he's doing it for learning purpose.I dont find it wrong in any way

Comment: It's like teaching a fisherman to catch fishes with a bazooka. Sure it kind of 'works', but it's not a good subject to discover REGEX.

Comment: @sputnick to me its like learning bike with clutch on.Though it is not right ,but you learn to ride the bike nevertheless(like balancing,braking and road sense).Then later on you learn to press it only when required.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern='/(?<=[\'\"])[\w\/-]+[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{3,4}(?=[\'\"])/i';
$regstring=$introtext;
preg_match_all($pattern,$regstring,$matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

you can see how this works here: http://regex101.com/r/eV6gE4/1

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper solution, and please, stop killing kitties (every-time you try to parse HTML with regex, you kill a kittie) when you install [perl module WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize), the command `mech-dump` become available :

```
$ mech-dump --images http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151348
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF63b.jpg?s=32&g=1
//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyAHT.jpg?s=32&g=1
/posts/27151348/ivc/677a
http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif
```

Comment: never heard of that mechanize earlier thanks for that,altough it seems really complex. i have to install a module for that right ? cause my module is for joomla cms is it viable for joomla development ?